# Can an UpdateView work without an object from the beginning?

Tags: django

Is there a way to use UpdateView without an object to update at first so I can pass it through AJAX? I want to create some sort of unique UpdateView for all the item where I can just select the item I want to update from a select.

Can I do this with UpdateView or I am going to need to code the view from scratch_

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In your UpdateView you should override get method (or post method, depending on what exactly you want to do), you can choose what your view does after that, for example:

```
    ...
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        if 'id' in kwargs:
            //perform update
        else:
            //do something else with AJAX
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by defining a `get_object` function in your view, and then accessing the relevant data in that function to determine which object is being updated.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object

For example:

```
class SomeUpdateView(UpdateView):

    ...

    def get_object(self):
        #access info from the URL, like <pk> or <slug>
        object_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        
        #alternatively access the request.POST or request.GET data
        some_info = self.request.POST.get('some_info')

        #return a model instance based on some data in this function
        return SomeModel.objects.get(pk=object_id)

    ...
```